# validate no file upload attached on a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to perform a check where if the user presses the submit button, if no file is attached then they will receive an alert to attach their file (a CV).

I have it working so that it determines which file types are allowed for upload onChange for the file upload button, but for the 'Buy Now' submit button, it doesn't perform an alert if no file attached.

```
<script src="components.js"></script>

<p>
<b>Attach your CV:</b> (.doc, .docx, .pdf, .txt, .rtf) 
<input type="file" id="uploadCV">
</p>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default buynow">Buy Now</button>

<script>
  var file = document.getElementById('uploadCV');

file.onchange = function(e) {
  var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
  switch (ext) {
    case 'doc':
    case 'docx':
    case 'pdf':
    case 'txt':
    case 'rtf':
      break;
    default:
      alert('Please upload a file that matches any of these file types: .doc, .docx, .pdf, .txt, .rtf');
      this.value = '';
  }
};

  </script>
```

components.js

```
function ValidateCVFile() {

    if( document.getElementById("uploadCV").files.length == 0 ){
        alert("Please attach your CV");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the **required** attribute as a simple solution. ex:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadCV" required>
```